# how to copy/move a column from one dataset to another dataset by matching variable

Tags: merge, dplyr, dataset

I have a Dataset1 which has 25 columns, with a single column for individual ID. I have Dataset2 with 15 columns and also a column for individual ID. I am trying to move or copy one of the columns from Dataset1 and put it into Dataset2 sorted by individual, but the same individuals are not necessarily in both datasets. Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried playing around with dplyr but I'm really new to R and haven't had any luck. I don't want to completely merge the datasets, I just want to add one column of data to the second dataset but without losing information on individual ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

an example

```
library(nycflights13) # for data example
head(flights)
head(airlines)
left_join(airlines, flights %>% select(carrier, flight))
```

your use case

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(Dataset1, Dataset2 %>% select(individual ID, name_col_to_copy) , by = "individual ID")
```